# Question on "sizeof" char pointer array in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, declaration, sizeof

I have two char arrays as below:

```c
char *t1[10];
char(*t2)[10];
```

when using sizeof to find their size

```
printf("sizeof(t1): %d\n", sizeof(t1));
printf("sizeof(t2): %d\n", sizeof(t2));
```

I found that the output is:

```
sizeof(t1): 80
sizeof(t2): 8
```

I am quite confused by why I have two different results when using the sizeof operator.

Comment: `char(*t2)[10];` is a *pointer to array* of ten `char`s. So it's size is a size of a pointer.

Comment: OTOH, `char *t1[10];` is an array of pointers. Not `char`s. So it is ten times as a size of a pointer.

Comment: I see, so the t1 have ten pointers and t2 is only a pointer to a ten char array. Why adding the "( )" on *t2 have this effect?

Comment: Because this is the syntax, as defined in the C language.

Comment: What is your goal here? What would you like to do? What are you expecting from this practice?

Comment: @Samuel One way to understand this is the "definition looks like use" rule. `char *t1[10]` means an item in t1 can be accessed with for example `*t1[5]` (which does [] first and then \* so it must be an array of pointers). `char (*t2)[10]` means an item in t2 can be accessed with for example `(*t2)[5]` (which does \* first and then [] so it must be a pointer to an array)

Comment: [cdecl](https://cdecl.org/?q=char%28*t2%29%5B10%5D%3B) can help with that.

Comment: @Neil great tool

Comment: @Samuel: Postfix `[]` has higher precedence than unary `*`, so `*a[N]` is always interpreted as `*(a[N])` ("array of pointers").  To specify a pointer *to an array*, you must explicitly group the `*` operator with the variable name: `(*a)[N]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters you have to use the conversion specifier `zu` instead of `d` when outputting values of the type `size_t`

```
printf("sizeof(t1): %zu\n", sizeof(t1));
printf("sizeof(t2): %zu\n", sizeof(t2));
```

This record

```
char(*t2)[10];
```

does not declare an array. It is a declaration of a pointer to the array type `char[10]`.

So `sizeof( t1 )` yields the size of an array while `sizeof( t2 )` yields the size of a pointer.

Consider for example declarations

```
char t1[5][10];
char ( *t2 )[10] = t1;
```

The pointer `t2` is initialized by the address of the first element (of the type `char[10]`) of the array `t1`. That is it points to the first element of the array `t1`.

Also consider the following call of `printf`

```
printf("sizeof( *t2 ): %zu\n", sizeof( *t2 ));
```

The output of the call will be `10`.

That is dereferencing the pointer you will get one dimensional array of the type `char[10]`.

If you want to get identical outputs then the second declaration should be rewritten like

```
char *t1[10];
char *( t2)[10];
```